# Testing Neo4j write performance with jlbh

Tags: java, performance, neo4j, latency

Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/yassinm/b3eb581ffb8bdfa8f7144d35eee59aed) for my test

I am trying to test the performance of neo4j writes (embedded and rest) using [jlbh](http://www.rationaljava.com/2016/04/jlbh-introducing-java-latency.html). Unfortunately i am not able to get anything beyond 50 nodes insertion per second (((

I am hoping that this is something to do with how i am configuring the multiple performance tuning nobs.

Config details:

- the jvm is oracle jdk1.8.0_77
- the server ulimit is set to 40000
- the server is an intel Ubuntu 14.04 server with 24gigs of ram.
- uname is (Linux ymo-dt 3.19.0-58-generic #64~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 18 19:05:43 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux)
- both the client and the server are running on the same machine (obviously since it is embedded)
- i figured once i know how to tune the embeded version i can go ahead and try the rest api with both client and server running separately
- I am trying to follow this so [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32729481/neo4j-node-creation-speed) in the tuning

  - As the gist (gradle part) says the version of neo4j i am testing is 3.0.1 from amven
  - I am passing Xmx and xms as both set to 4096m as per the gradle file
  - I cant for the life of me understand how that person got 7070 nodes insertion per second.

My questions :

1. What am i doing wrong ?
2. What do i need to add to the perfTuning section to make this reach 7000 nodes insertion per second ?
3. I am hoping that i am not going to need to batch the inserts at all. So the actual question is what is the maximum inserts i can achieve without resorting to batching ? or how ami supposed to do it with one tx per insertion ?
4. Once i move to the rest api what is the most performance tuned api i can use to access the server remotely ? I tried bolt and i am also not getting more than 38 nodes inserted per second.

## Edit:

Seems like ext4 is to blame here on linux. Even after mounting a tmpfs and using it in neo4j i am still getting around 300tps only (((

I mounted a tmpfs in /etc/fstab

```
tmpfs /mnt/data1 tmpfs defaults,noatime,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=1777,size=2G 0 0
```

Comment: It is important to note here that in your test you are writing one node per transaction. You can perform several thousand database operations per transaction. The example you link to is writing 750-1000 nodes per transaction.

Comment: I was hoping i will not have to resort to batching altogether because then error handling becomes way more complicated. I am not loading a huge file here. I am trying to simulate what would be the insert rate with one transaction per insertion. If everything i am doing is right (apart from batching) then 300tps on tmpfs is very bad in my use case (((

Comment: So far i could not find a solution for this ((( and batching is not an option for me. If 300tps is the max neo4j can do with a memory file system then it (unfortunately) sucks as at ingest ...